# How to merge to master branch after deleting everything in it?

Tags: git

I had 4 branches: `master`, `bg`, `bg2` and `bg2-2`. I think the issue started when I went from `bg2` to `bg2-2`, did everything I needed, liked the changes and went back to `master` to merge, that's when it gave me conflicts. So, what I did was delete everything in my `master` branch, saved it. Went back to my `bg2-2` branch and merged it to `bg2`. Than I tried it again but the `master` branch said everything is up-to-date so I went back to my `bg2` branch and merged to `bg`. I worked on some more code and committed, went back to the `master` branch to merge it but now I'm at a merging conflict on my `master` branch as it didn't commit all the files. I'm just looking at empty folders. How can I commit all the files from my remote branch to my master after I deleted everything from it?

Thanks.

Comment: so your master branch is currently empty? and you want to restore from the version held offsite?

Comment: @OliverAtkinson Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch --all
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will fetch all remote changes and remove all local changes.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson I did this and none of the files came to my master branch. When I did `fetch --all` it just says: `Fetching heroku`. When I do the `reset` afterwards, nothing changes - still no files.

Comment: @Jryl is your remote branch setup correctly? what shows when you type `git remote`

Comment: @OliverAtkinson After I do `git remote` it says `heroku`. (maybe because I push to Heroku?)

Comment: @OliverAtkinson Maybe I miscommunicated what I wanted. my `master` branch is empty and I want to get all the files from my `bg` branch. These are the only 2 branches that I have.

Comment: @Jryl what happens when you merge the two? IS that when you get conflict errors? If so you need to fix those errors and save the commit.     `$ git checkout master`
  then  `$ git merge bg`

Comment: @OliverAtkinson Yeah that's what happens it gives me the conflicts than and the branch will say `master | merging`.

Comment: @Jryl try use `git mergetool`